# Yellow screen of death only working in IE

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, yellow-screen-of-death

I have inherited a large application and whenever an exception occurs I get a screen of gibberish in **Chrome**:

[image]

However in **IE** it shows the yellow screen of death as expected:

[image]

I can't figure out why this would even happen.  Could it be an encoding problem?

**Edit** - Here are the request and response headers:

Request:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:.ASPXAUTH=5D3E8316B9AF0... [cut for brevity] 
Host:localhost:81
Referer: **************** [intentionally hidden]
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.96 Safari/537.4
```

Response:

```
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:6193
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 07 Nov 2012 16:42:15 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Answer (score 1):

Try debugging this case with the Chrome Developer Tools (menu *Tools* -> *Developer Tools*). Switch to the *Network* tab and reload the page. Now click on the file name in the left column and check *Headers* -> *Response Headers* -> *content-type* for the value *text/html* as well as *content-encoding* for *gzip*. Maybe the response is compressed but this is not correctly declared in the http headers.

Also look into the *Response* tab. Is the content there a readable html document?

Comment: Ya I checked that but didn't see anything obvious, the response content is all garbage just like it appears on the screen.  I've added the headers to the OP.

Comment: I thought that the response might be gzipped but no _Content-Encoding:gzip_ header is sent from the server. Maybe IE automatically detects compression but Chrome doesn't!? If you like to try you should be able to set a breakpoint in [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and insert this header.

Comment: I've actually narrowed it down to errors that occur in the view engine (Razor).  If I throw exceptions from the Controller they are handled fine but uncaught Razor errors produce the gibberish.